# Why doesn't my object code/machine code contain 1's and 0's

Tags: compilers

I know when I compile my C program to machine code it gets compiled into something that specific computer can understand

But I thought computers can only understand 1's and 0's (high/low) so why doesn't my program look like a bunch of strange symbols and not 1's and 0's?

ie: "UHâÂHÉÏHç=7∞Ë1…âE¸â»HÉƒ]√êˇ%¶LçïASˇ%ÖêhÈÊ"

There must be one last piece I'm missing where these symbols get converted to 1's and 0's somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of the program that opened the file.

All files on the system are in binary. What matters is how you interpret it.

The editor you used has displayed the digits in their common form:

"UH...." is the equivalent hexadecimal "5548...."  which is binary "101010101001000...."

Thus you need a Hex or Binary editing program to 'view' the '1's and '0's.

Comment: Here is a comparison of Hex editors. In general you don't 'edit' in binary, but rather in hexidecimal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Comment: I believe this program will 'display' any given file in the binary format you are looking for: http://www.proxoft.com/binaryViewer.aspx

Comment: if I use the command "xxd -b myfile.c" I can see the binary too. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765311/viewing-file-in-binary-in-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Machine/object code is specific to the interpreter/parser. What you mean to say by "1's and 0's" is binary code, which is what is presented to the machine when the interpreter/parser receives the machine/object code as input.

Comment: So at run time there is a parser that translates the machine code to binary code?

Comment: @MobileMon Yes, depending on the language. However, this is not necessarily true of all languages, but eventually, if the code is to be run on the machine, it is translated to binary at some point.

Comment: Now I'm not sure I quite understand. Please explain depending on the language. Also I'm not talking java or byte code here, I understand how the JVM works, I just mean the object file/executable file is not binary so at some point it needs to be binary

Comment: The Java compiler translates source code to machine/object code, and the Java interpreter translates machine/object code directly to binary, which is then sent off to the machine.

Comment: I think you are confused yourself, please see the accepted answer

Comment: Oh I see - I misunderstood the question.